# Load more data when FragmentStatePagerAdapter reaches the end of items

Tags: java, android

Question from Noob android developer

**Issue Defitition :**

I'm trying to achieve endless scrolling implement functionality of loading more data via network request when the FragmentStatePagerAdapter reaches last item, currently i'm setting static number for  getCount to 10//, what i'd like to do is trigger a network request as soon as it hits 7th item to get 10 more items and refresh the list, keeping the cycle going and potentially end up with more than 100 items hence why i'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, also store/cache the data so to support left to right & right to left swipe

**Here's what i've tried so far**

1. Read this article [infinite viewpager](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/looping-infinite-viewpager-with-page-indicator-in-android-ce741f25702a) however it only works for
   limited set of fragments perhaps a static number, what i'm trying to
   do is more dynamic as such  I dont have a fixed getCount.
2. Read the article [endless scrolling adapters](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView), i'm not trying to use 
   recycler view as viewpager works just fine for what i'm trying to do
3. Few more pageradapter implementations

**what i've learnt so far**
need to override getcount to return the maximum possible value

```
  public int getCount() {
   @Override
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  }
```

*I'm not sure if should also override getItemPosition or implement some kind on pageListener there are many examples available online using pagerAdapter/fragmentPageradapter i'm getting confused as to which ones are related to FragmentStatePagerAdapter and which ones are not

```
*
// My Framgent class
    public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_screen_slide_page_fragment,container,false);

        return rootView;
    }

    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance (String url){
        ScreenSlidePageFragment newFragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("imagePathUrl", url);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        return newFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        String imageUrl = getArguments().getString("imagePathUrl");

        if (imageUrl==null){
            Log.i("ScreenSlidePageFragment","no data passed");
        }else {
            Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(mImageView);
        }

    }
}

  // My adapter implementation

    public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        List<Resource> mResources;

        String url;

        Context mContext;

        private int NUM_PAGES = 5;

        private int currentPosition = 0;

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Resource> res,
                                       Context context) {
            super(fm);
            mResources = res;
            mContext = context;
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if (mResources != null & mResources.size() > 0){
                    url = mResources.get(position).getUrl();
                    Log.i("url",url);


                    return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(url);

                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"no results returned",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return null;
                }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (support.v13) and implement `getItemPosition` like this:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

> https://hedgehogjim.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/android-updatable-swipe-navigation-with-fragmentstatepageradapter/
>
> `return POSITION_NONE` "Causes adapter to reload all Fragments when notifyDataSetChanged is called"

Add a `OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager` and load more data after comparing the given `position` value with your current data size

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    //Load previous data set if position == 0
    //Load next data set if position == myAdapter.mResources.size() - 1
}
```

After the new data set has been loaded (and sorted), call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` then calculate and set the new index to match the old offset so the user don't see any shift

```
myViewPager.setCurrentItem(myNewIndex, false)
```

*Note: Sorting and new index calculation is only necessary when loading a previous data set.*

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer, the problem i'm having is getItem method from the adapter class is called before network data fetch is completed, how do i tell viewpager to stop running getItem till the async task is completed ?

Comment: `getItem()` should only be called after you return more than zero from `getCount()`. I use Kotlin async-await and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (on the main thread) after the data has been loaded.